# Twig: check a string doesn't end with another string

Tags: twig

In Twig you can easily check if a string `starts with` or `ends with` another string:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons

```
{% if 'Fabien' starts with 'F' %}{% endif %}

{% if 'Fabien' ends with 'n' %}{% endif %}
```

However, how do you find out if a string *doesn't* end with another one?  I'm doing something like checking a filename doesn't end in `.jpg` for instance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd tried various combinations like these unsuccesfully:

```
{% if not filename ends with '.jpg' %}

{% if filename ends with '.jpg' is false %}

{% if (filename ends with '.jpg') is false %}

{% if (filename ends with '.jpg') not true %}
```

In the end this was what I got to work:

```
{% if not (filename ends with '.jpg') %}
```

Comment: Those parenthesis are critical, hey :-)